# How to puts value from R in Ruby via rinruby

Tags: ruby, r

I need to be able to access the values created in my R code within R, like in this example.

```
require "rinruby"      
#Set all your variables in Ruby
n = 10
beta_0 = 1
beta_1 = 0.25
alpha = 0.05
seed = 23423
R.x = (1..n).entries
#Use actual R code to perform the analysis
R.eval <<EOF
  set.seed(#{seed})
  y <- #{beta_0} + #{beta_1}*x + rnorm(#{n})
  fit <- lm( y ~ x )
  est <- round(coef(fit),3)
  pvalue <- summary(fit)$coefficients[2,4]
EOF
puts pvalue
```

But I get errors:

```
 test.rb:21:in `<main>': undefined local variable or method `pvalue' for main:Object (NameError)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your last line to:

```
puts R.pull("pvalue")
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks! I see the pull method in the J. Statistical Software article now that you mention it

Comment: an alternative is `R.pvalue`